# tee pipeline killed before the end when signal caught

Tags: bash

I have this kind of script **program.sh** :

```
#!/bin/bash

catch_sigint()
{
    echo "program interrupted"
    exit
}
trap catch_sigint INT TERM

catch_exit()
{
    echo "program Exiting"
}
trap catch_exit EXIT

#rest of my program...
echo "program Running"
sleep 2
echo "program normal exit"
```

that is called by another script like that:

```
#!/bin/bash

catch_sigint()
{
    echo "script interrupted"
    exit
}
trap catch_sigint INT TERM

catch_exit()
{
    echo "script Exiting"
    kill -TERM $prog_pid
    wait $prog_pid
    echo "script END"
}
trap catch_exit EXIT


./program.sh &> >(tee -a log) &
prog_pid=$!
ps $prog_pid

# my code...
sleep 5
echo "script normal exit"
```

I can see on the terminal and in the log file that my program.sh is "Running". However I can't see that it is exiting. Indeed, when I do not do the redirection to **tee**, I can well see on the terminal that it is "Exiting", so the kill by pid is working.

So I think the **tee** redirection is killed at the same time than the **program.sh** but what I would like is to see the whole logs in the terminal and the log file. How can I do that ?

**Update on 13 March 2019**

I have updated the code to show the real use case that really show the issue. In fact, each script has its signal trap. So I guess that the **tee** redirection is interrupted as the rest of the program that's why it shows nothing. My output with interruption:

```
program Running
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 4922 pts/1    S+     0:00 /bin/bash ./program.sh
^Cscript interrupted
script Exiting
script END
```

My output without interruption:

```
program Running
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 4915 pts/1    S+     0:00 /bin/bash ./program.sh
program normal exit
program Exiting
script Exiting
./script.sh: ligne 13 : kill: (4915) - Aucun processus de ce type
script normal exit
script END
```

Comment: I can't replicate the problem. The only solution I have, you are calling `kill -TERM` before the other script registered the `trap .. EXIT`. [tutorialspoint](http://tpcg.io/kswlVG). Please provide a better mcve.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your response. I have updated my question because it wasn't a good description of my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your 2 scripts mimiking the run time by sleeps and printing the batch process. You can see the "Running" and the "Exiting" from the output. Probably, in your case the calling script kills the program.sh to quickly?

**program.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

catch_sigint()
{
    exit
}
trap catch_sigint INT TERM

catch_exit()
{
    echo "Exiting"
}
trap catch_exit EXIT

#rest of my program...
echo "Running"
sleep 2
```

**script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

./program.sh &> >(tee -a log) &
prog_pid=$!
ps $prog_pid

# my program...
sleep 1
# end of the program ...
kill -TERM $prog_pid
wait $prog_pid
```

As a result I get:

```
$ ./script.sh
Running
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 3081 pts/4    S+     0:00 /bin/bash ./program.sh
Exiting
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your response. I have updated my question because it wasn't a good description of my issue.